# Regex for matching either of two subdirectories any number of directories deep?

Tags: python, regex

I want to ignore all `.git` subdirectories AND `test` subdirectories.

The larger question is whether I can write this in a more readable way as NOT a regex.

I'm looking to specify the `rx` parameter of [compileall](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/compileall.html#public-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If regex is not desirable for the `rx` parameter, you can simply construct a class with a classmethod named `search` that satisfies the desired skip condition:

```
class MyRx(object):
    @classmethod
    def search(cls, p):
        return 'test' in p or '.git' in p
```

Usage

```
compileall.compile_dir('.', rx=MyRx, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address the larger question of whether a callback method can be supplied to `rx`, but this seems to work for me:

```
compileall.compile_dir('.', maxlevels=20, force=True, \
                       rx=re.compile(r'([/\\][.]git|[/\\]test)'), quiet=False, \
                       legacy=False, optimize=0)
```

Some docs on regex operators:

http://metahtml.sourceforge.net/documentation/regex/regex_3.mhtml